# How Do i change my whole app text in hindi and english without using String.xml because i have to much data

Tags: android

I want to change my whole app tex into Hindi or any other language 
Without using String.xml because of too much data so is there any way to
change the whole app into another language and can switch to eng also

Comment: so you want both English and Hindi?? Use Strings.xml

Comment: Yes nead to both English and hindi but not useaing String.xml

Comment: but String.,xml is the best way so i have to use it and i have done it thanku

Comment: You need to use Google and learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you only one solution - use special txt file with strings. But I will say surely that using String.xml is the best way of creating multilingual app. You will create as much as you need files with your locations and then you will call it when you will change language at the whole app.

**Another way** - use server which will send you all your big strings. But I'm sure it is too bad idea.

I have successfully made multilingual app with using only strings from String.xml. My own way in general works fine enough. So I'm sure that it is possible to use String.xml for creating multilingual app without any problems. Good luck and I hope that you will succeed in solving your problem :)

Comment: all text from answer, or only the main idea?